# Removing Empty Folders Using Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

I Have the following script I wrote to remote all empty folders from a very large Directory with many sub-directories. When I use it in a test environment, aka C:\Test containing folders that are empty, some that have only files, some with only folders, some containing both files and folders, there it works perfectly. But when I use it on the large directory it still asks me if I want to remove some folders with child items. I want it to delete the empty folders and ignore the folders that contain child-items. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
function removeEmptyItems($inst)
{
    $testInst = (($inst.FullName) + '\' + "*")
        if(($inst.PSIsContainer) -eq $true)
            {
                if((Get-Item -Path ($testInst) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force) -eq $null)
                    {
                        Remove-Item -LiteralPath ($inst.FullName) -Force
                    }
            }
}

# Change The Value For Set-Location To Wherever You Want To Trim
Set-Location "\\server\folder\subfolder"
Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse | 
%{ foreach ($inst in $_) { removeEmptyItems ($inst) } }
```

Thank you for any help I can get,

p.s. if you don't want to help and feel like down-voting, don't, comment and tell me why you feel that way so I can get better and my problem can be resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will clear out empty directories with no confirmations:

```
gci $Path -force -recurse|
    Where{$_.psiscontainer -and (gci $_.FullName -force -recurse|?{!$_.psiscontainer}).count -eq 0}|
        Remove-Item -Recurse -force
```

That looks for only folders, and then checks each one to see if it has files inside of it, if it has 0 files in it recursively it deletes the folder and any subfolders within it.

Comment: I tried it out but if ran for a few minutes and didn't find anything. I tried swapping out the Remove-Item live for Select FullName but that didn't find anything either. Looking at the code it looks like it should work but it can't find anything. I did look manually and confirmed there are empty child-directories.

Comment: This method should remove folders that have no files in _any_ subdirectory. Do the folders you expect to have been deleted have _any_ files in any of their subdirectories?

Comment: @Matt Yes the main directory has many sub-directories containing files. The main directory has well over 200,000 child items. I checked to make sure none of the file paths are over the 260 .NET limit for file path names and it's all set where I'm running it I just want to it to go through the the main directory's children and delete any empty folders anywhere in the tree.

Comment: @CalebB I'm curious to make sure the way you determine if a folder is empty. If it has no files in it own directory of if it has no files and any subdirectory. The latter is what this answer handles.

Comment: @Matt I was trying to sort the childitems by if they have any childitems(files or folders) themselves then moving down the chain of sub-folders. I worked out a C# solution that did what I wanted it to do but I'm still wondering why it had that error. for some folders way down the chain I get the System.IO filepath to long exception which I just added an erroraction tag to the gci action to silently continue but I wonder if those are the folders it's trying to delete if it doesn't see it's children because their path is to long? Or am I totally looking to far into that? No pun intended. ;)